# How to block an application (facebook, messages) in Self Control

Tags: macbook-pro, applications

I figured out how to do a while ago, but simply can't remember- how do I block computer applications such as twitter, facebook, and messages in self control?

Comment: I have the same problem. Stayfocus'd is very nice for Chrome, but there simply isn't anything just as good for safari, so I end up using it to waste a lot of time. I want to block safari permanently so I can't waste any time with it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot block apps, [as hinted in a github issue on their repository](https://github.com/SelfControlApp/selfcontrol/issues/142), only websites.

[Onefocus](http://onefocusapp.com/) is a similar app that seems to be able to do it. I have never tried it nor have any affiliation with it, so I cannot attest to its quality.

Answer (score -1):

You just click the "edit blacklist" button add the websites. Pretty simple. [image]

Comment: The question is clear about blocking apps, not websites. This does not tell how to block the Messages app, for example.